# CMake do something when command fails

Tags: cmake

I use CMake. A custom build step saves error output when it fails.

```
FIND_PROGRAM (BASH bash HINTS /bin)

SET (BASH_CMD "my-script input.file >output.file 2>error.file")

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND (
   OUTPUT output.file
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env ${BASH} -c "${BASH_CMD}"
   ...)
```

This works. If `my-script` fails for the given `input.file` then the stderr is saved in `error.file`, however when I run `make` and the target fails to build, the normal output does not make the location of `error.file` obvious. (The actual path of this file is generated in a tangly way.)

I don't want the noisy stderr to show in the terminal during `make`. I would like to do something like

```
MESSAGE ("input.file failed, see error.file")
```

(ideally coloured red or something) to be executed when the command for `output.file` failed.

Can I express this behaviour in CMakeLists.txt recipes?

Comment: What is wrong in adding `|| (echo "..." && /bin/false)` at the end of your command? E.g. `my-script input.file >output.file 2>error.file || (echo "input.file failed, see error.file" && /bin/false)`. Alternatively, you could create a standalone wrapper script, which redirects output of original script into a file and prints a message if original script fails.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the highlighting, but you could create a cmake script file executing the command via `execute_process`, check it's error code and print a custom message in case there's an issue. The following example runs on windows, not on linux, but this should be sufficient for demonstration.

**Some command that fails: script.bat**

```
echo "some long message" 1>&2
exit 1
```

**CMake script: execute_script_bat.cmake**

```
execute_process(COMMAND script.bat RESULT_VARIBALE _EXIT_CODE ERROR_FILE error.log)

if (NOT _EXIT_CODE EQUAL 0)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "command failed; output see ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/error.log")
endif()
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_custom_command(
   OUTPUT output.file
   COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/execute_script_bat.cmake")
```

Additional info can be passed by adding `-D "SOME_VARIABLE=some value"` arguments after `"${CMAKE_COMMAND}"`